# What's the standard to manage many to many relationships on REST APIs?

Tags: rest, laravel-4

I'm building a REST API using Laravel 4.2 that handles a (a few actually) many-to-many relationship: `Users` and `Account`s i.e. one user can manage many accounts and one account can be managed by many users.

So in order to create a user (this happens first) you should:

```
POST /users
```

In order to create an account and associate it to the previously created user, you should:

```
POST /users/{user_id}/accounts
```

So far so good. Now, what is the best (standard?) way to link/unlink a previously created user to a previously created account? From my point of view, this would have to be a PUT/PATCH request. So far, the best I could come up with is `PUT`ing an array with the associated ids to the entity URL:

```
PUT /users/{user_id}
{ accounts: [1,2,3] }
```

This would offer the ability to link AND unlink. But it would require the client to previously know what the **other** entity IDs are, and I don't want this for security reasons. I also came up with:

```
PUT /users/{user_id}/accounts/add
{ id: 4 }
```

and:

```
PUT /users/{user_id}/accounts/remove
{ id: 3 }
```

This is more powerful, but I don't really like it since the routes look a bit over complicated. Am I missing a better way?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way in REST is always defining a new resource. In this case what you need a resource which maintains these kind of relationships. You need the DELETE method to remove something and you need the POST to create something.

```
DELETE /users-accounts/user:{user_id}/account:{account_id}/
POST /users-accounts/ {user_id: 1, account_id: 2}
```

PATCH might be good if you want to do something with the whole relationship collection:

```
PATCH /users-accounts {remove: {user_id: 1, account_id: 2}}
PATCH /users-accounts/ {add: {user_id: 1, account_id: 2}}
```

So you can both add and remove many relationships in a single request. If you don't need this kind of bulk update, then the first solution will suffice.